# How can I build an Android device with two displays?

Tags: android

One of them would be a TV, the other a control display, with the menus. I assume I'd have to hack the Linux display driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick prototyping of the concept you can use a media center device running Android (or a phone) plus Android Wear as a second screen.

Comment: Thanks, Axi. I am using an Android tablet with Mobizen. I am interested in how this can work at the display driver-level, there have been a couple of phones 3-4 years ago (Yotaphone and a Kyocera) which had 2 displays, but nothing since.